# Wanted: Unix zip command-line program with zip64 support

Tags: 32bit-64bit, compression

Is there a Unix command-line program that implements ZIP with ZIP64 support? The standard zip program won't ZIP files bigger than 2**32 bytes.

I don't want to use `.tar.gz` format, because with ZIP I can access the files without decompressing the entire archive.

I don't want to use `7zip` because there is no native Python support for 7zip archives.

Thanks.

Comment: 7zip uses LZMA.  There's bindings for Python to LZMA.

Comment: Yes there are LZMA bindings for Python, but that doesn't mean that you can read 7zip files. It just means you can compress and decompress LZMA streams. Have you explicitly verified that 7ZIP files can be opened natively from Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked Info-zip was available for just about every OS ever invented and it does do zip64.
You may have to build it yourself for your particular system. You don't say which Unix you've got but there is a high chance they are pre-build packages available for yours already.

Just check out the  [home-page](http://www.info-zip.org/)

Comment: Wow. Turns out that the version of info-zip shipping with MacOS is from 2005! That's why it doesn't have 64-bit support.

Comment: The Unzip in Lion is indeed from 2005 (v5.52). The Zip is from 2008 (v3.0) which is also too old. v3.1 is the first that supports zip64.

Answer (score 1):

Debian (and every other major Linux distribution) package info-zip , which supports zip64, as zip/unzip, so that should be easier to get nowadays.
They also fix security issues unfixed in upstream.

https://packages.debian.org/buster/unzip

Comment: Thanks. BTW, the question is from 2012....